# Find the ideals of $S^{-1}R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, quotient-spaces

Here is what I want to prove:

Let $p$ be a prime integer, and consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}$. Let $S=\mathbb{Z}\setminus p\mathbb{Z}$. The ring $S^{-1}R$ is called the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$. Find all of the ideals of this ring, and describe the maximal ideal (there is only one).

For my proof:

Specifically, we know that $S^{-1}R=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\text{ }|\text{ }a\in R,b\in S\right\}$.

I have a theorem stating the following: If $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$ that does not intersect $S$, and $S$ has no zero divisors, then $\Phi(P)$ is a prime ideal in $S^{-1}R$, where $\Phi:R\to S$ defined by $\Phi(I)=\{\frac{x}{s}|x\in I,s\in S\}$. I think I want to use this here, but I still can't quite picture how these ideals would look in $S^{-1}R$.

Answer (score 1):

It's always true that the prime ideals of $S^{-1}R$ are in bijection with the prime ideals of $R$ that don't intersect $S$. When $R= \mathbb{Z}$ and $S= \mathbb{Z} - p\mathbb{Z}$, the primes that don't intersect $S$ are precisely those contained in the complement of $S$, or $p \mathbb{Z}$. But since $p$ is prime, the only such prime ideal is $p \mathbb{Z}$ itself. As a subset of $S^{-1}R$, this is the set of fractions $x/s$ such that $x \in p \mathbb{Z}$.

Can you describe the rest of the ideals?

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I suppose one thing that still confuses me is how this set of fractions $\{\frac{x}{s}|x\in p\mathbb{Z}\}$ satisfies the absorption property of ideals? For example, if $p=5$, what elements would this set contain? Could $x$ be any multiple of 5, and $s$ could be any element in $S$?

Comment: That's correct, since the multiples of $5$ are precisely the elements of $5 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: In regard to describing the rest of the ideals, I believe this prime ideal is also the only maximal ideal of the ring, because maximal implies prime. Then, that would mean all other ideals must be contained within this ideal?

Comment: @MathStudent1324 That's right. In general, whenever we have a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq R$, the localization $R_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ is a local ring, hence the name. Here $R_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ is standard notation for $(R-\mathfrak{p})^{-1}R$.

Comment: Thanks! Back to the $p=5$ example, maybe the other ideals would have elements looking like $\frac{nx}{s}$ where $x$ is still from $p\mathbb{Z}$, but $n\neq 5$ is some fixed prime in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @MathStudent1324 Although the bijection one gets on prime ideals fails for ideals in general, the ideals of $S^{-1}R$ are all *extended*. This means that any ideal in $S^{-1}R$ is generated by the image of an ideal $I$ coming from $R$. One must simply verify, as in this case, that $I$ doesn't generate the unit ideal in $S^{-1}R$.

Comment: Okay, I think this make sense. If possible, could you provide an example of such an ideal in the $p=5$ case?